# How can I make blank DGV columns default to numeric without inserting zeros...the equivalent of "" for string?

Tags: vb.net

Several of the Stack Overflow posts come close to resolving my problem but one of you experts can best tell me the best place in my code to resolve my issue...in the file saving or file loading code...or somewhere else.

My desktop application has an 11 column DataGridView. Column 0 is reserved for the row number, added after sorting. I load string data in columns 1 through 5 and integer data in columns 6 (with some rows blank) from a CSV text file using Microsofts TextFieldParser. I may load some new string data in columns 1 through 5 (in new rows) and integer data in columns 7 (with some column 7 rows blank) from a different CSV text file using Microsofts TextFieldParser. With a calculate button event I add the integers in columns 6 and 7 and display the sum in column 11. At this time I can add integers in any of the blank cells of columns 6-10 or change the integers 
anywhere in columns 6-10 and click on the calculate button and the correct sum is displayed in column 11. It also sorts ascending or descending by clicking once or twice on the column 11 header. Now I save the entire DGV in a CSV text file using streamwriter. See code below. Later I reload the entire DGV CSV text file so that I can now add more integer data in column 8 without having to reload the integer data of columns 6 and 7. Now when i enter integer data in a blank cell or change data in columns 6-10 and click on the calculate button there is no response and looking at the suming code I see I am trying to add integers to cells with "" in them. The problem, "" cannot be converted to zero. Is Nothing the answer for a zero without entering zero? The Summing code snippet: For c = 0 To Dgv0.Rows.Count-1 (next line) Dgv0(11, c).Value = CInt(Dgv0(6, c).Value) + CInt(Dgv0(7, c).Value) + ... CInt(Dgv0(10, c).Value). The "" did not exist in the blank cells until after reloading the entire CSV text file. How can I make blank cells act like zeros (without adding zeros) instead of "" empty strings.

```
Using WriteFile As New StreamWriter(addToFile)
For x As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Rows.Count - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1
        WriteFile.Write(Dgv0.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value)
           If y <> Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1 Then
               WriteFile.Write(",")
           End If
    Next
    WriteFile.WriteLine()
Next
End Using
```

The reloading code

```
Using readFile As New StreamReader(reloadFile)
    Do While readFile.Peek() <> -1
         seriesStr = readFile.ReadLine()
         seriesArr = Split(seriesStr, ",")
         Dgv0.Rows.Add(seriesArr)
    Loop
    readFile.Close()
    readFile.Dispose()
End Using
```

Comment: My suggestion is to dump the CSV format and use a JSON as storage (if you really don't want a simple database). You can deserialize the saved JSON to a DataTable, preserving the type of your data (so, Intergers will be Integers and not Strings as you have now, for example). The deserialization/serialization process is just one single command (using a DataTable). All the heavy work is done by the JSON serializer/deserializer. See [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), if you havent already. You can add it to your Project using the NyGet Package Manager. Lots of code samples around, too.

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires using a mouse click and a press of the delete key, however it does work. I hope someone can show code to replace the mouse click and the delete key press. I added two lines of code to the save as CSV text file. It now looks like:

```
   Using WriteFile As New StreamWriter(addToFile)
        For x As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Rows.Count - 1
            For y As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1
                If Dgv0.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value = Nothing Then
                    Dgv0.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value = 0
                    'need code here to press the delete key which is ASCII 46
                End If
                WriteFile.Write(Dgv0.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value)
                If y <> Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    WriteFile.Write(",")
                End If
            Next
            WriteFile.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Using
```

What happens is all of the blanks are filled with zeros. By clicking on the cells with zeros and then pressing the delete key the zero is removed but the cell still acts like the zero is still there, i.e., you can add cell values with results as if the zeros are still there. To me, this is the equivalent of an empty string, for an integer.